# running chef-solo recipe in windows

Tags: chef-recipe, chef-solo

I  want to run chef-solo in windows , by installing recipes in the system .

I have downloaded the recipes and .json from here : 
https://github.com/markshead/chef-solo-demo

I have placed the repo in D:\repo
So, I opened the cmd prompt in that location  and executed the command:

**D:\repo>chef-solo -j dna.json**

I get an error as : **Cookbooks not found.** Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Chef is telling you that it can't find the cookbooks. Normally with chef-solo you have a solo.rb file that points to the path where your cookbooks are located. You can explicitly set this with "-c solo.rb".